# Select all values if any value like condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got three tables:

companies:

```
____________________________________________________________
|           id                |           company          |
____________________________________________________________
|            1                |         'Sunflower'        |
___________________________________________________________
|            2                |         'Chamomile'        |
____________________________________________________________
```

companies_services

```
____________________________________________________________
|         company             |           service          |
____________________________________________________________
|            1                |              1             |
___________________________________________________________
|            1                |              2             |
____________________________________________________________
|            2                |              1             |
____________________________________________________________
```

services

```
____________________________________________________________
|           id                |            service         |
____________________________________________________________
|            1                |           'sales'          |
___________________________________________________________
|            2                |         'distribution'     |
____________________________________________________________
```

**DDL SQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE companies ("id" int, "company" varchar(9));
INSERT INTO companies ("id", "company") VALUES (1, 'Sunflower'),(2, 'Chamomile');

CREATE TABLE companies_services ("company" int, "service" int);
INSERT INTO companies_services  ("company", "service")VALUES    (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1);

CREATE TABLE services   ("id" int, "service" varchar(12));
INSERT INTO services    ("id", "service")VALUES (1, 'sales'),   (2, 'distribution');
```

and query:

```
SELECT companies.company 
       services.service
FROM companies
LEFT JOIN companies_services ON comapnies.company = companies_services.company
INNER JOIN services ON companies_services.service = services.service
WHERE services.service LIKE '%distr%'
```

With this query I've got only "distribution" service, but company may contains more services, I need to select them too. How to check condition if company contains service, which like %value% then select all services, else select nothing?

Result must be something like

```
____________________________________________________________
|           company           |            service         |
____________________________________________________________
|         'Sunflower'         |            'sales'         |
___________________________________________________________
|         'Sunflower'         |           'distribution'   |
____________________________________________________________
```

Comment: The WHERE clause condition makes the second LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data, I don't see you need LEFT JOIN. Here is the query >>

```
SELECT c.company,
       s.service
FROM   companies AS c
       INNER JOIN companies_services AS cs
              ON c.id = cs.company
       INNER JOIN services AS s
               ON cs.service = s.id
WHERE  c.id IN (SELECT c1.id
                FROM   companies AS c1
                       INNER JOIN companies_services AS cs1
                              ON c1.id = cs1.company
                       INNER JOIN services AS s1
                               ON cs1.service = s1.id
                              AND s1.service LIKE '%distr%');
```

Comment: This solution is much more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This works too :

```
select companies.company, services.service  from companies
inner join (select companies_services.company from services 
            inner join companies_services on companies_services.service=services.id 
            where services.service like '%distr%') as company_id on company_id.company=companies.id
inner join companies_services on companies_services.company = companies.id
inner join services on services.id = companies_services.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
with CTE as (
    select company from companies_services T1
    left join services T2 on T1.service = T2.ID
    where T2.service like '%distr%' 
)
select T3.company,T2.service from companies_services T1
left join services T2 on T1.service = T2.id
left join companies T3 on T1.company = T3.id
where T1.company in (select company from CTE)
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

---

[Online Test Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=2b67803097a86e8b4debea659f20ee42)

Comment: That's not it. I was added expected result to question

Comment: I fix it . @SimatsuEdgeworth

Answer (score 0):

If you put the services into a single column, then this is easy:

```
SELECT c.company, ARRAY_AGG(cs.service) as services
FROM companies c JOIN
     companies_services cs
     ON c.company = cs.company 
GROUP BY c.company
HAVING SUM( (cs.service LIKE '%distr%')::int ) > 0 ;
```

Notes:

- The `services` table is not needed because the column you want is in `company_services`.
- The outer join is not needed, because you are requiring a match.
- Table aliases make the query easier to read and write.

If you want separate, then window functions are the way to go:

```
SELECT company, service
FROM (SELECT c.company, cs.service,
              SUM( (cs.service LIKE '%distr%')::int ) OVER (PARTITION BY c.company) as cnt
      FROM companies c JOIN
           companies_services cs
           ON c.company = cs.company 
     ) c
WHERE cnt > 0;
```